# Incorrect argument to CreateThread

Tags: c++, c, dword

```
#include <windows.h>

DWORD Menuthread(LPVOID in) { return 0; }

int main()
{
    CreateThread(NULL, NULL, Menuthread, NULL, NULL, NULL);
}
```

I'm getting the following error message:

```
error C2664: 'HANDLE CreateThread(LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES,SIZE_T,LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE,LPVOID,DWORD,LPDWORD)': cannot convert argument 3 from 'DWORD (__cdecl *)(LPVOID)' to 'LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE'
note: None of the functions with this name in scope match the target type
```

Comment: Please stop creating multiple accounts [and posting duplicate questions to stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58903588/could-someone-tell-why-createthread-is-not-working). You will get better help if you take the time to read the [help], take the [tour], and read [ask].

Comment: i just need help no one helped it would be cool if you can help me asap

Comment: People on stackoverflow.com will be happy to help you if you follow directions for creating questions that are answerable. You are posting questions with missing information that makes it impossible for anyone to figure out the issue. The rule of thumb that you should follow is to ask yourself the following question: can anyone cut/paste the shown code, compile, and reproduce your problem themselves? If the answer is "no", how can anyone possibly tell you what the problem is? P.S., this doesn't mean you should post all your code, but only a [mre].

Comment: Sorry for the abuse you received on your previous question, some people still aren't nice to new users if they don't produce a perfect question on their first attempt. As Sam said we need a [mre]. Potentially all we need is the includes and the declaration of your variables. It's really difficult for us to help you with a compiler error when you haven't given us the full code which reproduces said error.

Comment: if i would paste everything i would leak a battle eye and easy anti cheat bypass and a working driver to :D the aimbot and esp only work together...

Comment: You don't need to post everything, we need a [mre], emphasis on "minimal", delete all irrelevant parts of your code until you have a minimal amount of code that shows the error. This process will often allow you to solve the problem yourself by highlighting exactly where the problem is

Comment: this is the "shortest" version i could give is the problem... could you write me on Discord or somewhere else then i would send you the full source mapper and driver. NettyInjection#9999

Comment: No sorry that isn't how stack overflow works, the answer to your question becomes part of the knowledge base of possible programming problems for other users to find, solving it privately isn't the goal. If you want private help contract a professional programmer!

Comment: uhm i really dont want to leak my bypasses and stuff i allready sended shortest version. my includes are #include "DirectOverlay.h"
#include <d3dx9math.h> to draw esp to see the "source" look up

Comment: adding in the missing parts your code compiles: https://godbolt.org/z/mWWCmy the error must be in the code you have omitted

Comment: there is the whole source without driver and bypass. https://godbolt.org/z/YtDsrJ

Comment: Again trimming down to just your main function the code compiles: https://godbolt.org/z/p6ETkh where exactly are you seeing your error message?

Comment: it says missing file but i have this file this is not the error the error is: Schweregrad Code Beschreibung Projekt Datei Zeile Unterdrückungszustand
Fehler C2664 "HANDLE CreateThread(LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES,SIZE_T,LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE,LPVOID,DWORD,LPDWORD)" : Konvertierung von Argument 3 von "DWORD (__cdecl *)(LPVOID)" in "LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE" nicht möglich D2DOverlay Test External C:\Users\notsp\Desktop\fortnite_usermode_get_ids\Source.cpp 398

Comment: A minimal example would be this: https://godbolt.org/z/dNzPXZ does it compile for you?

Comment: it does not compile it compile online but not on my pc

Answer (score 6):

If you are compiling on 32-bit visual c++ the default calling convention is `__cdecl`. `CreateThread` expects a `__stdcall` function pointer. The simplest fix to this is to use the `WINAPI` macro which should be defined to the correct calling convention for the platform you are using:

```
#include <windows.h>

DWORD WINAPI Menuthread(LPVOID in) { return 0; }

int main()
{
    CreateThread(NULL, NULL, Menuthread, NULL, NULL, NULL);
}
```

Alternatively use `std::thread` and just use the default calling convention, this also means you can pass parameters to your function without having to cast them to `void*`:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <thread>

DWORD Menuthread() { return 0; }

int main()
{
    std::thread thread(Menuthread);
}
```

Comment: thx for your help  now xor.hpp and thread sucks i think i quit the project.